# name 'navigation_draw' is not defined in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

for creating toolbars in kivyMD, i have watched following youtube tutorial : [toolbars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iicfEqNBb-4)

and here is code :

```
from kivymd.app import  MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size=(700,700)
screen_helper ="""
Screen:
     BoxLayout:
          orientation:'vertical'
          MDTopAppBar:
               title:'My First App'
               left_action_items:[['menu',lambda x: navigation_draw()]]
          MDLabel:
               text:'hello App'
               halign:'center'
"""
class MobileApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen =Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

    def navigation_draw(self):
        print("Navigation")

MobileApp().run()
```

it runs without any problem, here is image :
[image]

when you click here is this error :

```
  File "<string>", line 7, in <lambda>
 NameError: name 'navigation_draw' is not defined
```

i have checked following tutorials :
https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.0/components/navigation-drawer/index.html

but did not get clue how to solve this problem , could you help me please

Answer (score 1):

my fault   was that i missed app part, here is my solution :

```
from kivymd.app import  MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size=(700,700)
screen_helper ="""
Screen:
     BoxLayout:
          orientation:'vertical'
          MDTopAppBar:
               title:'My First App'
               left_action_items:[["menu",lambda x: app.navigation_draw()]]
          MDLabel:
               text:'hello App'
               halign:'center'
"""
class MobileApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen =Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

    def navigation_draw(self):
        print("Navigation")

MobileApp().run()
```

when i click, i got following text :

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\User\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-05-08_23.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Data_Science\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Data_Science\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.1, git-Unknown, 2023-04-30 (installed at "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Data_Science\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 516.94'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <32768>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
Navigation
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```